# unexplained symbols retrieved from url

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I am running a SQL query to insert data and send a notification to the user.

```
$query = "INSERT QUERY";    
$result = mysql_query($query);
$last_entry = mysql_insert_id();
```

The notification code.

```
$params = array("access_token"=>"MY_ACCESS_TOKEN","template"=>"Sample template","href"=>"index.php?id='$last_entry'");
$response = $facebook->api("/" . $reciever_id . "/notifications","POST",$params );
```

In the index page I am catching the id and echo-ing it using the following code-

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $message_id = $_GET['id'];
    echo $message_id;
}
```

Although everything works fine and data storage as well as notification functionality work,but in the index page i get the id as \'35\' if my id in table is 35. Why are \' added to the start and end of the id?

And if \' are unavoidable,is there any php function that will help me eliminate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `single quotes` from `$last_entry`, like,

```
$params = array("access_token"=>"MY_ACCESS_TOKEN",
                "template"=>"Sample template",
                "href"=>"index.php?id=$last_entry");
$response = $facebook->api("/" . $reciever_id . "/notifications","POST",$params );
```

Also check that, Did you get the `expected id` in `$last_query`?

You can check for `numeric` in your condition like,

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) and is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
    $message_id = $_GET['id'];
    echo $message_id;
}
```